# Python, code works in the command line, but not when trying to create a program, please

Tags: python

... could someone explain the difference?

What I type in the command prompt:

```
sys.path.append('M:/PythonMods')

import qrcode
myqr = qrcode.make("randomtexxxxxxxxxt")
myqr.show()
myqr.save("M:/myqr.png")
```

MAKES A QR FOR THE TEXT.

The code I type:

```
sys.path.append('M:/PythonMods')

import scipy
from qrcode import myqr 

file=open('myqr3.png',"r")
myqr.show()
file.close()
```

It doesn't recognise `sys`, do I need to import something? How come it runs in the command prompt?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes, you need to import `sys`. If it runs in the interpreter, you probably *already* imported `sys`.

Comment: If you are using `ipython` as your interpreter shell, then note that it does import a number of modules for you for convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add at the begining of your source file:

```
import sys
```

and while we're reviewing your code, in executable source files it is advised to do so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('M:/PythonMods')
import qrcode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myqr = qrcode.make("randomtexxxxxxxxxt")
    myqr.show()
    myqr.save("M:/myqr.png")
```

so your code will run only when you execute it as a file, not when you import it. You may want to define your three lines as a function, and call your function in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part, to be able to reuse it like any library!

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the script, please include the following line:

```
import sys
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys` is not a built-in, you do need to explicitly import it:

```
import sys
```

The `ipython` interactive shell imports a lot of modules by default; perhaps you are using that to test your code. The *default* Python runtime does not import `sys` for you.